# Is there any SQL Online tool for assesment and validating code

Tags: webapp-rec

I need a online tool for validating SQL code. Assesment quetions will be given the person writes code for it and submit. I need to validate the code and generate report.

Is there any tool for doing the above process. If no tool exists please tell me some sugestions to implement the same.

Comment: For validating, see http://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/

Answer (score 4):

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4) it's a great website you can write your sql queries to testing them and share it with others.